# opencti VM credentials

Tags: security, virtual-machine

I can't access to the openCTI VM. I have followed this tutorial : https://www.notion.so/Virtual-machine-template-1789b4442b414dbf87f748db51c85aa5.

I launched the opencti-release-4.3.4.ova but this don't provide the credentials to lauch the VM. What are the login and the password ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a little oversight of update in the documentation concerning the password :

`login : opencti`

`password : opencti`